# Generate NSDate of this type: 2015-04-27T10:45:52Z

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter

I am trying to set the date to PayPal pre-approval key in the following way:

```
@"2015-04-27T10:45:52Z", @"startingDate",
```

This date works, however I don't know how to reproduce it in code terms. I tried doing:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateformate=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateformate setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz"]; // Date formater
NSString *date = [dateformate stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

but this doesn't work. What is the Z at the end of the date?

Comment: Times are expressed in UTC (Coordinated Universal Time), with a special UTC designator ("Z").

Comment: Didn't you notice that the date format you're using doesn't match the format you claim to want?  Have you consulted [the documentation](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns)?

Comment: __[OFF]__ it seems every `NSDate`-related post is the same nowadays and none of the posters really has done any minimal effort to search for solution/information first. __[ON]__

Comment: What is the reason for the down-vote?

Comment: @holex Is that actually different for any other topic here on SO? ;-)

Comment: @Alessandro This was likely down-voted because this question has been asked many, many times before. This really doesn't demonstrate your having done any research. E.g. search for "NSDate T" or "NSDate Z" and you'll see lots of related questions.

Comment: I've been trying to figure out why this question merited an upvote.

Comment: @DanielRinser, sometimes a question makes different but it is actually completely identical to many date-formatter related posts – the guys just forgot to read the documentation entirely. :( btw, here is [documentation on Apple's site](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html) which is missed every occasion. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your date format is not correct. Second, for consistent results, you should always hard-code the `en_US_POSIX` locale (the date formatter defaults to the user's locale):

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];   
[dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"];
```

Alternatively, I've had positive experience with [iso-8601-date-formatter](https://github.com/boredzo/iso-8601-date-formatter). ISO 8601 is a surprisingly complex standard with **lots** of edge cases, and this library seems to be able to cope with most of them.

Answer (score 0):

The `Z` stands for Zulu (i.e. UTC/GMT). If you want to generate a date string in that format (GMT with `Z` qualifier), please refer to [Apple's Technical Q&A #1480](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1480/_index.html), which reminds us to specify both `locale` and `timeZone`:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setLocale:[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"];
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
```

Or in macOS 10.12 and iOS 10, you can do:

```
NSISO8601DateFormatter *formatter = [[NSISO8601DateFormatter alloc] init];
```

And then you can do:

```
NSString *dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```